# FFMPEG: Have the video title appear once at the beginning and then again at the middle of the video with drawtext

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, time

Im streaming a live video using FFMPEG to youtube, what i would love to do is draw a text title on the video at various parts of the video such as at the first frame for 20 seconds and then again every 45 seconds there after. So far I have the below code working:

```
"-vf" ,  "[in]drawtext=fontsize=20:fontfile=/home/streamer/fonts/Timeless.ttf:textfile=/home/streamer/video_title.txt:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.8:boxborderw=5:x=W-w+5:y=h-th-50:enable='between(t,0,20)+between(t,45,65)'[out]
```

It successfully makes the title appear at 0-20 seconds and then again at 45-65 seconds, is there a way to dynamiclly make it come lets say at the exact center of the video and end of the video programatically?

Like take T/2 and calculate the title to appear in the middle for T/2-20 seconds?

Comment: Not automatically possible. You have to probe input duration (let's call it `X`) then it will be `enable='between(t,0,20)+between(t,X/2-20,X/2)+gte(t,X)'`

Comment: @gyan thank you , is there no constant/variable in FFMPEG that automatically represents the duration of the current media FFMPEG is handling as input? or do i have to probe it separately lets say in a shell or python script and pass it to FFMPEG

Comment: Yes, there is no constant.